# How does AppSettings in VB.NET windows Forms work?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, appsettings

Hello I have build a small app to demo a concept in C# in which I added the application config file etc added System.Configuration dll to the reference and accessed the settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
   <add key="username" value="myknownusername"/>
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

No news It worked flawlessly with the code:

```
private String username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
```

Now I have been asked to do the port the app to VB.NET and to my biggest surprise. It's been a while that I opened visual studio in VB.NET project. I was surprised to see an already white dashed `App.config` file so I added my `AppSettings` section and after 3 hours I still can't get the value of the username using the same ConfigurationManager

```
Dim username as String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("username")
```

I have included another application configuration `app1.config` which by the way has generated entries already. I could not get anything with the app1.config either.It also returns `Nothing`

```
       </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I am really perplexed as how a simple reading of configuration file could be this challenging in VB.NET unless I am using the  wrong method which I always use in C#.

Kindly point me to whatever I am not doing right.

**EDIT**

As you can see in the picture below, I have all it needs to work properly.I as expecting to read the setting key from either App.config or app1.config. When I run like shown below the MessageBox is empty

[image: screen shot of the project]

Comment: It is working as expected - are you sure you're the right app.config is in place?

Comment: Edited the post with screenshot with both  app1.config and App.config. Kindly show where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Have you checked your Debug\Bin folder if the app.config file is in place? Its called YourAppname.exe.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit, I needed to right click the generated App.config and choose `Include In Project`. that's it. it's weird because I never do that in a C# project.